# How to turn a dictionary into attribute = value

Tags: python, dictionary, type-conversion, exec, eval

I have the following dictionary in Python:

```
myDic = {}
myDic['username'] = 'smith44'
myDic['password'] = '123'
myDic['email'] = 'smith@gmail.com'
```

I want to turn this into:

```
username = 'smith44'
password = '123'
email = 'smith@gmail.com'
```

so that I can directly use username, password and email directly in one of my latter methods. I know I can use the dictionary but I need to do it this way for the sake of compatibility.

Again, what I need to do here is turn every dictionary key into a seperate attribute that will take the value of its corresponding dictionary value.

**UPDATE**
To further support what I need to do, here is what I've done so far:

```
    for key, value in myDic.iteritems():
        exec("%s = " "'""%s""'" % (key, value))
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you're calling a function, you can unpack straight from the dictionary: `somefunc(**myDic)`. If you mean "how can I make the dictionary values into local variables", I suggest you leave them in the dictionary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please have a look at my question again. I fixed a couple of semantical errors so I can better communicate my point. What I essentially need is a number of statements that will be executed on runtime.

Comment: It's still not clear. Please explain more about what you are trying to do, and why. Generally, using `eval` is a bad sign.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Edited my post again. Should be all clear now.

Comment: 1. Don't do this, just use the values from the dictionary. 2. Ok, so what's the *problem*? Errors? Unexpected outputs?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It seems that my solution works afterall. It's just that there was an error with my input causing all sorts of weird compiler popups which made me believe that `exec` was wrongly implemented. However @Carsten makes a very good point too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really really need to do this:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['test'] = "foo"
>>> locals().update(d)
>>> test
'foo'
```

But if I were you, I'd try to find a different way of solving the problem you're trying to solve instead of automatically adding variables to your local namespace. There's almost always a way around this mess.

Comment: @Konos5 I've seen the update, and my code does the thing you want. If you don't understand any part of that example, please explain.

Comment: Indeed your solution worked. My bad I didn't pay some proper attention the first time around! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you will get string in `attribute = value` format using `str.join`

```
In [12]: ", ".join(["%s = %s" % (k, v) for k,v in myDic.items()])
Out[12]: 'username = smith44, password = 123, email = smith@gmail.com'

In [13]: myDic.items()
Out[13]: [('username', 'smith44'), ('password', '123'), ('email', 'smith@gmail.com')]
```

Comment: I don't need one string. I need a number of attribute-value pairs that will be generated from `myDic`.

Comment: This will produce a SyntaxError, the correct way to multiply assign is `username, password, email = "smith44", "123", "smith@gmail.com"`. Also note that in your solution you're not assigning `smith44` as a string but as a variable which, unless already defined elsewhere, will produce a NameError.

Comment: @Lafada I just edited my post to clarify a few things. What you are suggesting here is a list of tuples which I don't need. I just need a number of attribute=value pairs.